# In Reactjs production mode, my app does not change url and not rendering component while I use Browser router, but it works fine with hashrouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './home'    
import {Link,Switch,Route,BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDom.render(
    <BrowserRouter>        
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>        
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

HashRouter works in production mode but BrowserRouter doesn't change urls and not rendering component also

Comment: Can you see any console errors in your console?

Comment: did the issue occur  in local or hosting ?